# DRF nested serializers custom output

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework, nested

Couldn't find problem like this, so here is my problem:

*models.py (simplified)*

```
class Root(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class TextFile(models.Model):
    root = models.ForeignKey(Root)
    name = models.CharField()

class ImageFile(models.Model):
    root = models.ForeignKey(Root)
    name = models.CharField()
```

*serializers.py*

```
class TextFileSerializer(serializers.Modelserializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TextFile
        fields = '__all__'

class ImageFileSerializer(serializers.Modelserializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ImageFile
        fields = '__all__'

class FilesSerializer(serializers.Modelserializer):
    Texts = TextFileSerializer(source='textfile_set', many=True, read_only=True)
    Images = ImageFileSerializer(source='imagefile_set', many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Root
        fields = '__all__'
        
class RootSerializer(serializers.Modelserializer):
    files = FilesSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Root
        fields = '__all__'
```

I've got only root 'id' and 'name' in output but no 'files'.

I expect output like this:

```
{
    'id': 0,
    'name': 'Root instance 1',
    'files': {
        'Texts': [
            {'id': 0, 'name': 'Text1'},
            {'id': 1, 'name': 'Text2'},
             ...
        ],
        'Images': [
            {'id': 0, 'name': 'Image1'},
            {'id': 1, 'name': 'Image2'},
             ...
        ]
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `FilesSerializer` field in `RootSerializer` is always returning None because Root have no property named 'files'. DRF serializer don't add None fields in the response by default. Your FileSerializer ask for a RootModel.

What you want is a way to retrieve files from your root model, so what you can do is using a SerializerMethodField, and in this method, fetch the data you need, and serializer them using your FileSerializer (but as a normal serializer).

Like so :

```
class TextFileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = TextFile
    fields = '__all__'

 class ImageFileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ImageFile
        fields = '__all__'

 class FilesSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
     Texts = TextFileSerializer(source='textfile_set', many=True)
     Images = ImageFileSerializer(source='imagefile_set', many=True)

     class Meta:
         fields = '__all__'
    
class RootSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    files = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Root
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_files(self, instance):
        return FilesSerializer(instance).data
```

It returns

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "files": {
            "Texts": [],
            "Images": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "testimage",
                    "root": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        "name": ""
    }
]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! My head was about to blow)